# Accessing Drivers

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I am fairly new to Linux and am trying to figure out how I can view/access the drivers on my system to see how they are written so I can write my own drivers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look over the information in the aforementioned post